# Sinon stub within ffmpeg error event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, sinon

```
    const {writeStream, upload} = S3Service.uploadStream({ Bucket: process.env.BUCKET, Key: s3Path});

    ffmpeg(stream)
        .outputOptions('-copyts')
        .audioCodec("libopus")
        .toFormat("matroska")
        .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                upload.abort();
                return reject("Error FFMPEG");
            }
        })
        .on('start', (p) => console.log(p))
        .on(`end`, () => console.log("end ffmpeg"))
        .pipe(writeStream);

    upload.promise()
        .then(() => resolve("Successful audio converted transfer"))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I have the code above and I'm writing a unit test for it as follow:

```
let uploadStreamStub = {
    writeStream: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
    upload: {
        promise: sandbox.stub(),
        abort: sandbox.stub()
     }
}

sandbox.stub(s3Service, "uploadStream").returns(uploadStreamStub);
```

I'd like to stub upload.abort():

```
let onStub = sandbox.stub(ffmpeg.prototype, "on").returnsThis();
onStub.withArgs("error").yieldsAsync(new Error("test"));
sandbox.assert.calledOnce(uploadStreamStub.upload.abort);
```

However, the stub is not working:
**AssertError: expected stub to be called once but was called 0 times**

When I remove the "yieldsAsync" line and try to stub the promise it works:

```
// onStub.withArgs("error").yieldsAsync(new Error("test"));
sandbox.assert.calledOnce(uploadStreamStub.upload.promise);
```

**So the stub only doesn't work on('error'...**

What I'm doing wrong?

How can I stub and check if abort has been called?

Comment: `yieldsAsync` sounds like it's intended to mock a generator function, which doesn't seem to be happening here. Did you by chance want something more along the lines of `resolves()`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem,
instead of

```
onStub.withArgs("error").yieldsAsync(new Error("test"));
```

I changed it to:

```
onStub.withArgs("error").yields(new Error("test"));
```

Now it works as intended.